# Python : Mocked return value of parameter passed by reference to a C library

Tags: python, mocking, ctypes

I have a C library that I am writing a wrapper for. Most of the functions in this library take 'an out arguments' (the result is returned in the variable passed).
So how do I test the case when:
 - self._system returned as None (from C as a side effect), but
 - the function returns success

Please see the code below for more details

main.py

```
myLibDLL = CDLL('mylib.dll')

class System():
    _system = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._system = c_void_p(None)

    def GetSys(self):
        # - The C function prototype 
        #       ERROR_CODE XXX_API CGetSys(void* phSys)
        # - myLibDLL.CGetSys() is the call to mock
        retErr = myLibDLL.CGetSys(byref(self._system))
        checkReturnErr(retErr)

        if self._system.value == None:
            raise BaseException('Failed to Get Sys') # case to test
```

unit tests file

```
@patch("main.myLibDLL.CGetSys")
def test_GetSys_sysIsNone_afterCGetSysisCalled(self, mock_CGetSys):
    self.sys = System()

    # What expectations shoudl I set here?
    mock_CGetSys.return_value = 0 # to pass checkReturnErr()        
    mock_CGetSys.??? = None # the question 

    # test
    with self.assertRaises(BaseException):
        self.system.GetSys()
```

Comment: Good. And what's the problem? You're not even asking anything.

Comment: Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking questions, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @DawidFerenczy thanks for the feedback ... please check the updates.

Comment: Why is `_system ` both *class* and *instance* member? Also, you didn't expose(*C*'s) *CGetSys* signature (*SO* alone would reveal lots of answers related to the current situation). At the end, try to learn about one thing at a time  (*ctypes* can be a tricky topic, while decorators (which involve descriptors - one of *Python*'s most powerful, used and misunderstood features) is another **heavy** one).

Comment: @CristiFati `_system` is a `c_void_p` type that I pass around to the C API, and the `_system` naming is irrelevant to the question. The `XXX_API` in the code is the macro that exposes the C API functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a function that has the same signature as the C function.
- Assign that function to the mock's side_effect.

  ```
  def nullifyCSysPtr(cSysPtr):
      # assigne None to c_void_p type
      cSysPtr._obj.value = None

  @patch("main.myLibDLL.CGetSys")
  def test_GetSys_sysIsNone_afterCGetSysisCalled(self, mock_CGetSys):
      # moking
      mock_CGetSys.return_value = 0 # to pass checkReturnErr()        
      mock_CGetSys.side_effects = nullifyCSysPtr # the answer

      # test
      with self.assertRaises(BaseException):
          self.sys = System()
          self.system.GetSys()
  ```